# How to change the pivot point, transform origin, or point of rotation for an object A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

When I draw a `<a-box>`. The localization is in the center of the box. The rotation rotates about the center of the box. How do I change the point of rotation?

```
<a-box rotation="0 45 0"></a-box>
```

Answer (score 10):

One way is to wrap the object in a parent entity, offset the position of the inner entity, and then apply transformations to the parent entity.

The code below will shift the point of rotation (or transform origin) on the Y-axis by 1 meter.

```
<a-entity rotation="0 45 0">
  <a-box position="0 1 0"></a-box>
</a-entity>
```

This pivot component might also work:

```
var originalPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
var originalRotation = new THREE.Vector3();

/**
 * Wrap el.object3D within an outer group. Apply pivot to el.object3D as position.
 */
AFRAME.registerComponent('pivot', {
  dependencies: ['position'],

  schema: {type: 'vec3'},

  init: function () {
    var data = this.data;
    var el = this.el;
    var originalParent = el.object3D.parent;
    var originalGroup = el.object3D;
    var outerGroup = new THREE.Group();

    originalPosition.copy(originalGroup.position);
    originalRotation.copy(originalGroup.rotation);

    // Detach current group from parent.
    originalParent.remove(originalGroup);
    outerGroup.add(originalGroup);

    // Set new group as the outer group.
    originalParent.add(outerGroup);

    // Set outer group as new object3D.
    el.object3D = outerGroup;

    // Apply pivot to original group.
    originalGroup.position.set(-1 * data.x, -1 * data.y, -1 * data.z);

    // Offset the pivot so that world position not affected.
    // And restore position onto outer group.
    outerGroup.position.set(data.x + originalPosition.x, data.y + originalPosition.y,
                            data.z + originalPosition.z);

    // Transfer rotation to outer group.
    outerGroup.rotation.copy(originalGroup.rotation);
    originalGroup.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);
  }
});

<a-entity pivot="0 1 0" rotation="0 45 0"></a-entity>
```