# Controll Camera Rotation 360 Image A-Frame

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I cant find any documentation on how to controll the Camera Rotation on A Frame ? I have a 360 image implementated as the  element. The Image or i.g. the Camera should rotate as i just move the mouse over the screen - move mouse right -> move image right and so on.

Its no Problem to read out the position of the pointer but how can i set the camera to rotate by a specific Angle so that the 360 image will "rotate" for the user ?

Best regards

Comment: How about rotating your 360 image element instead?

Comment: I dont think that there is a way to rotate the sky, isnt it ? Also i didnt found antoher simple way to display a 360 iamge instead of settting it as reference to the sky element - maybe you can tell me more about how you would do this ?

Comment: Have you tried <a-animation> on your elements? this will work with any object including a-sky

Answer (score 0):

You should rotate the relevant elements instead of the camera since it's not a good practice to rotate it.

Ref:

1. [How to change the rotation axis for an animated A-Frame object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42838501/how-to-change-the-rotation-axis-for-an-animated-a-frame-object)
2. https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/2898